# Running Intern tests using PhantomJS and Travis CI

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, automated-tests, travis-ci, intern

#### Context:

I'm running some unit tests using the Intern framework. Since the code I'm testing is a package I published on NPM, I wanted to integrate it with Travis CI.

On my local, all the tests run fine. With Travis CI, however, the tests stall because of starting the PhantomJS webserver.

This is my Travis CI file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "4"
env:
  - CXX=g++-4.8
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - g++-4.8
before_script:
  - bower install
  - npm install grunt-cli -g
  - grunt installation
  - phantomjs --webdriver=4444
```

Because the `phantomjs` command starts a webserver, it never runs `npm test`. It just halts on the webserver.

#### Question:

How do I make it so that I can run `npm test` after starting PhantomJS? Is there some way I can move that process to the background, or start another process to run my tests? Or is there some way of calling both `phantomjs --webddriver=444` and `intern-runner config=tests/intern` at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Travis CI commands are simply shell commands you should be able to start phantomjs and then continue along by [forking it](http://www.hacktux.com/bash/ampersand):

```
- phantomjs --webdriver=4444 &
```

(Note the ampersand at the end.)

You may also need to add a `sleep` to give the process time to start, since it doesn’t appear that PhantomJS has a way to daemonize itself or touch a pid-file when it is ready.

There are also plenty of other scripts and/or Grunt tasks you can use to run PhantomJS, but this should be the minimal change necessary to solve your problem.

Comment: Good answer just to add if u decided to switch to gulp then consider super test which brings up a server for the test run and then shuts it down all as part of the test suite

Comment: @CSnover thanks for always answering my intern-related questions. This does solve the issue with it hanging, but now I'm [running into this issue](https://github.com/theintern/leadfoot/issues/24). Guess I've gotta look up resources on using Selenium on Travis CI instead of Phantom JS :/